# Ember.js classNameBindings is not firing when Ember.set is called from afterModel in App.Route

Tags: ember.js

What I would like to do is set the selected duration to a default value based on whether a cookie has been set or not. I am performing this check in the afterModel of App.Route.

If a cookie has been set, use the cookie value, if not set it to the first member of the durations array.

The class name is bound to the Duration Button Component and is working as expected after an initial value has been selected.

I am new to Ember and wondering if I am just going about this the wrong way or have I missed something?

```
App.Route = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      categories: categories,
      durations: durations
    })
  },
  actions: {
    setDuration: function(duration) {
      var idx = durations.indexByPropertyValue('selected',true);
      if (idx >= 0 ) {
        Ember.set(durations[idx],'selected',false);
      }
      idx = durations.indexByPropertyValue('seconds',duration);
      if (idx >= 0 ) {
        Ember.set(durations[idx],'selected',true);
        $.cookie('duration', duration)
      }
    }
  },
  afterModel: function(posts, transition) {
    var duration = $.cookie('duration');
    if (duration) {
      var idx = durations.indexByPropertyValue('seconds', duration);
      if (idx >= 0) {
        Ember.set(durations[idx],'selected',true);
      }
    } else {
      duration = durations[0].seconds;
      Ember.set(durations[0],'selected',true);
      $.cookie('duration', duration)
    }
  }
});

App.DurationButtonComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['btn btn-default'],
  classNameBindings: ['selected:active'],
  selectedBinding: "duration.selected",
  tagName: 'button',
  click:function (){
    if (this.duration.selected) return;
    this.sendAction('action', this.duration.seconds);
  }
});


var durations = [
  {
    id: '1',
    num: '15',
    unit:'sec',
    seconds: 15,
    selected: false
  },
  ...
  {
    id: '5',
    num: '5',
    unit:'min',
    seconds: 300,
    selected: false
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set/observe properties you need the duration to be an [ember object](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html).

```
App.Route = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      categories: categories,
      durations: [
        Ember.Object.create({
          id: '1',
          num: '15',
          unit:'sec',
          seconds: 15,
          selected: false
        }),
        Ember.Object.create({
          id: '5',
          num: '5',
          unit:'min',
          seconds: 300,
          selected: false
         }),
      ]

     })
  }
});
```